# Generic List is not coming

Tags: c#, linq, intellisense

This sample uses `where` to find all products that are out of stock.

```
public void Linq2()
{
    List<Product> products = GetProductList();

    var soldOutProducts =
        from p in products
        where p.UnitsInStock == 0
        select p;

    Console.WriteLine("Sold out products:");
    foreach (var product in soldOutProducts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is sold out!", product.ProductName);
    }
}
```

Result:

Sold out products:

- Chef Anton's Gumbo Mix is sold out!
- Alice Mutton is sold out!
- Thüringer Rostbratwurst is sold out!
- Gorgonzola Telino is sold out!
- Perth Pasties is sold out!

The above example i got from [MSDN Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336760#WhereSimple1), this is Simple2, the problem is when I enter `List<Products>`, *Products* is not showing in Intellisense. When I enter it manually, I get the following error:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement and new object expression
>   can be used as a statement

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: so your problem is that the editor/compiler cannot find `Product` right? Have you added all the needed references or the definition of the class/struct itself?

Comment: @CarstenKönig: Yes editor/compiler cannot find Product, i am new LINQ, i just done, what they said in that link. Is that anything i have to add extra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

your problem is that you copied the linked source. But this source does not contain the definitions for neither `Product` nor `GetProductList()`

Please take a look at the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) - it has everything you need:

```
List<string> fruits =
    new List<string> { "apple", "passionfruit", "banana", "mango", 
                    "orange", "blueberry", "grape", "strawberry" };

IEnumerable<string> query = fruits.Where(fruit => fruit.Length < 6);

foreach (string fruit in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(fruit);
}
```

Comment: Konig: Is that in that link they used "Northwind" database?

Comment: Konigg: So in that link, they gave something only, after that we have to do remaining, is it correct?

Comment: I guess so - the samples are just a collection of stuff. It should be obvious how to use it but it's a pain to just copy'n'paste - the MSDN Docs examples are far better for this

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't have the class defined. You to add the class definition. You could write the class in the same file, add a new class file and put the definition of Product in it.